# Code inside submit event executes after or before form submitting?

Tags: jquery

Does the code inside `$('form').submit(function() {});` executes **before** or **after** the form submit?

For example, if I edit the value of one of the inputs there, will the new value be included on the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It executes before the form submits. Otherwise the page would have changed, and since the JavaScript environment is associated with the page, it would have changed too. That would leave you executing in a potentially rather odd context.

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />');
});
```

Will mean that every form will have that input appended before submitting (assuming JS is enabled).

Similarly:

```
$("#someForm").submit(function() {
    if (/* something */) {
        alert("Form invalid"); //alert() is terrible, but you get the point
        return false; //Blocks submission
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

(Note: depending on the situation and other bindings, using `preventDefault` would likely make [more sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) -- I'm just lazy.)